# Terraform kubernetes commands failing with private GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I have launched a **private** [GKE cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html) using terraform resource `"google_container_cluster"` with a `private_cluster_config` block in it.

I have added `master_authorized_networks_config` to allow my own IP address in authorized networks for the GKE.

And I have added [k8s namespace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/namespace.html) using terraform resource `"kubernetes_namespace"`.

I have also set all google, kubernetes providers, k8s token, cluster_ca_certificate etc correctly and the namespace was indeed provisioned by this terraform.

---

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "k8s_cluster" {
  # .....
  # .....
  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes = true
    enable_private_endpoint = false
    master_ipv4_cidr_block = "172.16.0.0/28"
  }
  ip_allocation_policy { } # enables VPC-native
  master_authorized_networks_config {
    cidr_blocks {
      {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        display_name = "World"
      }
    }
  }
  # .....
  # .....
}
```

```
data "google_client_config" "google_client" {}

data "google_container_cluster" "k8s_cluster" {
  name     = google_container_cluster.k8s_cluster.name
  location = var.location
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  # following this example https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_client_config.html#example-usage-configure-kubernetes-provider-with-oauth2-access-token
  version = "1.11.1"
  load_config_file = false
  host = google_container_cluster.k8s_cluster.endpoint
  token = data.google_client_config.google_client.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
    data.google_container_cluster.k8s_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate
  )
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespaces" {
  depends_on = [google_container_node_pool.node_pool]
  for_each = ["my-ns"]
  metadata {
    name = each.value
  }
}
```

---

Then I ran `terraform apply` and the namespace was created fine ✅✅✅

```
kubernetes_namespace.namespaces["my-ns"]: Creating...
kubernetes_namespace.namespaces["my-ns"]: Creation complete after 1s [id=my-ns]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

---

However, when I run `terraform apply` or `terraform plan` again and terraform is trying to refresh the namespace resource,

```
data.google_container_cluster.k8s_cluster: Refreshing state...
kubernetes_namespace.namespaces["my-ns"]: Refreshing state... [id=my-ns]
```

it's throwing the following error **intermittently**. ❌ ❌ ❌

```
Error: Get http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/my-ns: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

It's sometimes passing and sometimes failing - **intermittently**.

---

Where would you advise I should look into to fix this intermittent error?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the source of the issue was [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/import.html#provider-configuration):

> The only limitation Terraform has when reading the configuration files is that the import provider configurations must not depend on non-variable inputs

In your case, your kubernetes `provider` block has several config options that are variables:

```
  host = google_container_cluster.k8s_cluster.endpoint
  token = data.google_client_config.google_client.access_token
```

My workaround was to create a kubeconfig.yaml file and temporarily replace the provider config with something like the following:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "kubeconfig.yaml"
}
```

This allowed me to run the import, and then I restored the previous variable-based config.

Comment: Hi. This would be great if the k8s configs were fixed. We were having dynamic configs across different projects and environments. Hence, we needed to use variables.

Comment: The problem i later realized was, i was overriding the kubernetes provider of this module from the parent/calling module - I was passing `provider { kubernetes = kubernets }` from the parent/calling module. That was causing a conflict (although intermittent, don't know why) with the kubernetes provider. Once, i removed the overriding, it was fine since then.

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue with k8s contexts. You should create dedicated unique k8s context to access Your GKE cluster and specify it in terraform provider

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context = var.K8S_CONTEXT
  version        = "1.10"
}
```

Check `kubectl config get-contexts` to get list of all Your k8s contexts.

Terraform resource may be useful to create context of Your GKE automatically

```
resource "null_resource" "local_k8s_context" {
  depends_on = [google_container_cluster.gke_cluster_0]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${var.GKE_CLUSTER_NAME} --project=${var.GCP_PROJECT_ID} --zone=${var.GKE_MASTER_REGION} && ( kubectl config delete-context ${var.K8S_CONTEXT}; kubectl config rename-context gke_${var.GCP_PROJECT_ID}_${var.GKE_MASTER_REGION}_${var.GKE_CLUSTER_NAME} ${var.K8S_CONTEXT} )"
  }
}
```

Comment: i am not loading any config file. I am using token and cluster_ca_certificate like this example for private GKE cluster https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_client_config.html#example-usage-configure-kubernetes-provider-with-oauth2-access-token
Would it be suitable in this case?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Example you're referencing uses 'https' scheme, while I see 'http://localhost/' in your error. Do you use multiple kubernetes providers?

Comment: i have just added my code snippets in the question. I haven't used multiple k8s providers

Comment: Could you pls create separate google_container_cluster datasource and use it instead of  resource, same as in referenced Terraform example ?

Comment: i just upated the code snippet with `data.google_container_cluster.k8s_cluster`. Still the same results. :( :( :( Intermittently failing with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can report the issue on https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues it's a good place to report issues with Terraform and GPC.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... this looks more like a problem with the `kubernetes` provider than with the `google` provider. 

I have reported the bug here. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/821